# VC++ Making a single line text box act (mimic a button) on the return key

Tags: c++

I am learning Visual C++ 2010 Express on windows XP

This must be a standard task I am trying to do!!!

I have a very basic form with an input text box, an output text box and a button

I enter a value into the input text box and press the button and the answer is displayed in the output  text box.

This all works.

I want to press the return key after I have enterd the value into the input textbox (single line box) and have the answer displayed in the output textbox. (the same as pressing the button).

Is this not a simple thing to do?

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I haven't looked into the exact mechanics of how pressing enter when done typing to hit the button works, but I had it working when they both had `WS_GROUP` and the button was `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`. Try playing around with those.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to break the news, but you are not writing C++ code.  The language you are using is called C++/CLI, a managed language that resembles C++ about as well as C# does.  The dead give-away is writing code that uses the ^ hat.  Easy to see in the code that the GUI designer generates for you.

The Express edition you use is a major cue, it only supports creating GUIs by using C++/CLI.  By taking advantage of the Winforms class library and the designer it supports.  Very nice, you can plop controls on a form and double click them to implement the default event.  Adding the Click event for a button is trivial.

The native way, MFC, is not supported in that edition.  And is urky, MFC has no designer support beyond creating dialogs.

Biggest thing about a GUI app is that is does *not* use the Enter key to move from one control to another.  Users are familiar, and know, to press the TAB key instead.  The Enter key is reserved to operate the OK button in a dialog.

It is not like you couldn't make it work, Winforms is flexible enough to let you trap the Enter key to change the focus.  it is just that you shouldn't, users know when they are not working with a console mode app and are happy to use the TAB key.

Wrong language, wrong UI mode, not what the school you went to told you about, I guess.  They don't.

Comment: Thanks I was aware in the back of my mind  it was not C I had seen references to CLI now I understand

It’s not the C that is causing me problems it’s the windows form type stuff

What I really need is a book/website on this other stuff, a complete list of these things

I expected it to be just a property set to true sort of thing

Finding out about things like;

    Convert::ToString(int_varible)
    Application::Exit()

   And when to use ->  and the fullstop for properties or whatever they are?

Is a bit of a struggle, time consuming

But thanks for the feedback it cleared a few things up